# Instance resets to default after stop/start

Tags: openstack

I installed ***nova + glance*** on my laptop. I ran an instance type ***m1.tiny*** with Ubuntu 10.04 image. Then I installed apache2 and run a wordpress site on this instance. Everything fine!

But when I reset my laptop (host machine) or stop the instance, then when I start it again, every package I installed is gone. The instance is "blank" like the brand new after I created by "euca-run-instance".

Is it the default config of Openstack or and error on my laptop?
What should I do if I want to reuse the instance?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question a long time ago when I tried to run Openstack on my laptop hardware. There was many annoyances, after each time turn off and turn on my laptop to test Openstack, the instance I created last time was not run or it broke. I reinstall OP and fixed these problem. Each time run OP, I must reboot the instance and nova service... several times then it works.